# Unexpected token in node.js

Tags: node.js

js for the 1st time, attempting to develop a bot using Microsoft's bot framework for Azure in node.js.

The only code i added to the below full code (which was a template) is this:

```
.matches('None', (session, args) => {
session.send('Hi, this is the None handler. You said: \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});
```

Here is the full code:

```
"use strict";
var builder = require("botbuilder");
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");
var path = require('path');

var useEmulator = (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development');

var connector = useEmulator ? new builder.ChatConnector() : new botbuilder_azure.BotServiceConnector({
    appId: process.env['MicrosoftAppId'],
    appPassword: process.env['MicrosoftAppPassword'],
    stateEndpoint: process.env['BotStateEndpoint'],
    openIdMetadata: process.env['BotOpenIdMetadata']
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.localePath(path.join(__dirname, './locale'));

// Make sure you add code to validate these fields
var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v1/application?id=' + luisAppId + '&subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

// Main dialog with LUIS
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
/*
.matches('<yourIntent>')... See details at http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/guides/understanding-natural-language/
*/

.matches('None', (session, args) => {
    session.send('Hi, this is the None handler. You said: \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});

.onDefault((session) => {
    session.send('Sorry, I did not understand \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});

bot.dialog('/', intents);    

if (useEmulator) {
    var restify = require('restify');
    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.listen(3978, function() {
        console.log('test bot endpont at http://localhost:3978/api/messages');
    });
    server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());    
} else {
    module.exports = { default: connector.listen() }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at eval (eval at compileFunc (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11015\bin\edge\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:1:80)
    at compileFunc (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11015\bin\edge\double_edge.js:35:16).
2017-07-12T18:21:57.420 Function started (Id=71b6a39b-ebca-4bc4-a642-5e7cfb68c921)
2017-07-12T18:21:57.420 Function completed (Failure, Id=71b6a39b-ebca-4bc4-a642-5e7cfb68c921, Duration=0ms)
2017-07-12T18:21:57.436 Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\index.js:42
.onDefault((session) => {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Comment: As the parser is trying to tell you, `'.'` is wrong,

Comment: And if you'll try to remove the semicolon after `matches `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are chaining functions here

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })

.matches('None', (session, args) => {
    session.send('Hi, this is the None handler. You said: \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});
  ^ should be removed

.onDefault((session) => {
    session.send('Sorry, I did not understand \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});
```

So semicolon after `matches.(...)` is redundant